# Как в telethon получить все сторисы канала

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Я пытался получить их с помощью такого кода:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetFullChannelRequest

api_id = ''
api_hash = ''

client = TelegramClient('gorkiiogurec', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    dialogs = await client.get_dialogs()

    ch = await client.get_entity('канал с сторисами')
    ch_full = await client(GetFullChannelRequest(channel=ch))
    print(ch_full)

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Но в `ch_full` не было ничего об сторисах. И вообще, можно ли их как-то достать?